# How to take the previous number if it is 0 then take the previous month's number using LAG syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, gaps-and-islands, sql-server-2019

[image]

Source Data :

```
Account Period  Amount
AC100   January 100
AC100   February    0
AC100   March   0
AC100   April   0
AC100   May 0
AC100   June    600
AC100   July    700
AC100   August  0
AC100   September   0
AC100   October 1000
AC100   November    0
AC100   December    1200
```

I use this query

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Account,
        Period,
        Amount,
        LAG(Amount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PreviousAmount
    FROM TableA
)
SELECT
    Account,
    Period,
    CASE WHEN Amount = 0 THEN PreviousAmount ELSE Amount END AS Amount
FROM CTE
```

but the results only take the previous month which has an amount like the following picture:

[image]

How do I ensure that amount 0 remains filled with the previous number?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If you're on 2022, this is somewhat simpler, due to the implementation of `IGNORE NULLS`. What version are you using?

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` doesn't provide any kind of deterministic ordering. If you want the "previous" to be well defined and not subject to unwanted changes you need to order by a column/expression that provides the required ordering

Comment: @ThomA I use all year

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FIll null values from previous records in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929736/fill-null-values-from-previous-records-in-sql-server)

Comment: What version *of SQL Server*? Run `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: this has been answered a gazillion of times, you have 0 instead of NULLs but the principle is the same. One can also use window functions to solve this

Comment: btw, i learned that `order by @@spid` was better than `order by (select null)`

Comment: @siggemannen - It isn't "better" - neither are correct in this case. I think I saw previously that using `@@SPID` blocked a parallel plan

Comment: yeah, sorry, i meant in general case where you don't care about sort. I think @@trancount blocked parallel plan.

Comment: @MartinSmith I use version Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @siggemannen - maybe something that has changed. In the past I definitely noticed a case where changing from `@@SPID` to `SELECT 0` changed the plan from serial to parallel but yeah you are right https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbf77.png

Comment: *"I use all year"* What..?

Comment: Are the values always ascending? If so, you just want the maximum.

Comment: *"Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5"* Out of interest, why haven't you *ever* installed an update, or even a security update, on your instance in the last 4 years?

Comment: `max(Amount) over (partition by Account order by month(cast(Period + ' 2023' as date))`

Comment: Are you familiar with what to do [when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

This is a *gaps and islands* problem, You can solve it using window function `sum()` to calculate a running total, this creates islands where rows with consecutive months have the same rn value.

The `max()` window function used to find the maximum amount within each island for each account.

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(Amount) over (partition by Account order by MONTH(Period + ' 1 2014') ) as rn
  from TableA
)
select Account, Period, max(Amount) over (partition by Account, rn ) as Amount
from cte
```

Results :

```
Account Period    Amount
AC100   January   100
AC100   February  100
AC100   March     100
AC100   April     100
AC100   May       100
AC100   june      600
AC100   july      700
AC100   August    700
AC100   September 700
AC100   October   1000
AC100   November  1000
AC100   December  1200
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/q8aO-CRN)

Answer (score -1):

Using your example data:

```
create table #data
(
    Account varchar(5),
    [Period] varchar(9),
    amount int
)

insert into #data values
('AC100','January',100),
('AC100','February',0),
('AC100','March',0),
('AC100','April',0),
('AC100','May',0),
('AC100','June',600),
('AC100','July',700),
('AC100','August',0),
('AC100','September',0),
('AC100','October',1000),
('AC100','November',0),
('AC100','December',1200)
```

You can achieve this with an `OUTER APPLY` to find the last non-zero `amount` and return that instead when the `amount` value is zero:

```
select
    d.Account,
    d.[Period],
    case when d.amount = 0 then lastNum.lastAmount else d.amount end as amount
from #data d
outer apply
(
    select top 1 amount as lastAmount
    from #data l
    where month(l.[Period] + '1 1900') < month(d.[Period] + '1 1900')
    and l.amount <> 0
    order by month(l.[Period] + '1 1900') desc
) lastNum
```

Results:

| Account | Period | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AC100 | January | 100 |
| AC100 | February | 100 |
| AC100 | March | 100 |
| AC100 | April | 100 |
| AC100 | May | 100 |
| AC100 | June | 600 |
| AC100 | July | 700 |
| AC100 | August | 700 |
| AC100 | September | 700 |
| AC100 | October | 1000 |
| AC100 | November | 1000 |
| AC100 | December | 1200 |

Comment: @Arif Please don't write "thank you" in comments when an answer helped you. You can upvote the answer and/or accept it as answer that soved your question by clicking the checkmark on the left (the last option is possible for one answer only).